# Deduce inequality between geometric mean and power mean from AM-GM

Tags: algebra-precalculus, means

Below is exercise 20 from Tom Apostol's "Calculus" Vol. 1 (2nd edition). I need help solving part (b).

> The geometric mean $G$ of $n$ positive real numbers $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ is defined by the formula $G = (x_1x_2,...x_n)^{1/n}$.
>
> *(a)* Let $M_p$ denote the pth power mean. Prove that $G \le M_1$ and that $G = M_1$ only when $x_1 = x_2 = ... = x_n$.
>
> *(b)* Let $p$ and $q$ be integers, $q \lt 0 \lt p$. From part (a) deduce that $M_q \lt G \lt M_p$ when $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ are not all equal.

One of the previous exercises introduced the below theorem, which looks like something that may be used here, but I'm not sure exactly how. I know that every $q \gt 1$ satisfies $q \gt 2p$ for some $p$, but that would still require to show that either $M_q \gt M_{2p}$ or $M_q \gt G$.

> If $p \gt 0$, $M_p \lt M_{2p}$ when $x_1, x_2,..., x_n$ are not all equal.

This exercise is hard! I've spent 3 hours doing part (a) and didn't manage to do it alone, but found solution in [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#Proof_by_induction). Still have no idea how to do part (b).

Assuming that this comes from *Introduction* to Calculus book, please don't use any advanced theorems. Ideally, if you have the book, consult it to know what theorems were introduced so far and are available to use.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things 
about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if 
you write what your thoughts 
are on the problem and include your efforts (work in progress) in 
this and future posts and in what context you have encountered the problem; this will prevent people 
from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers 
at the right level.

Comment: @JKnecht: Thanks for the information. I added a theorem that I think seems like a good fit here, but I'm not sure how exactly use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: write the AM-GM inequality for numbers $x_1^p, x_2^p, \ldots, x_n^p$. Raise the inequality to the power $\frac 1p$.

Comment: Sure! After all it was so simple... I even remember trying that in my head, but I think I didn't notice that in geometric mean, that after raising to $1/p$ power in geometric mean all $p$ powers will be removed. I guess it shows that it's always better to write ideas down instead of simply going over them in your head. And thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The point b) is a consequence of the fact that power mean function $M_p$ is strictly increasing if $x_1, x_2, \dots$ are not equal.

If you take the derivative of $M_p$, i.e., $\frac{d}{dp}\left(\sum_iw_ix_i^p\right)^{1/p}$, it is not complicated to show that the derivative is stricly positive (using e.g. Cauchy-Schwarz inequality) and thus $M_p$ is increasing function of $p$.

That knowing, it follows that for any $q<p$, $M_q<M_p$.

Also the geometric mean is just a special case when $\lim_{p\to0}M_p=M_0=G$.

And thus also if $ q<0<p$, then $M_q<M_0<M_p$.